# Cast Companion Library MiniController Buttons

Tags: chromecast

Is there anyway to change the `MiniController` video control buttons to the "white" variety (R.drawable.ic_av_pause_dark, R.drawable.ic_av_play_dark, etc)?

The drawables are set to private in the `MiniController`. I suppose I can copy all the "white" ones, and rename them as the black ones, but didn't know if there was another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no other way. I will address this in the next update (please open a ticket on the GitHub project for it so I don't forget). In the update, I will use more generic names for those drawables like ic_mini_controller_pause, etc and then you can update the resource in your own project, or I may use an "alias" so you can point that alias to light or dark version in your project.

Comment: Thanks.  Here is the ticket: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/issues/40